# jQuery page has no style and doesn't look right

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have tried everything I can think of, but my page loads weirdly. With no style or form, and for the life of me, I have no clue why! Here is my code below : and attached is a picture of the outcome I get when running the code.

[My outcome when I run this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPUMk.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery Mobile Demos</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="_assets/js/index.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">    

    <div data-role="header">
        <div class="ui-btn-active" data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>    
                    <a href="#">Find Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Call Us</a>
                </li>
            <ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-content" data-role="main">
        <ul data-filter="true" data-insert="true" data-role="listview">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Brussels</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dublin</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Cape Town</a>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        <div data-role="footer" style="text-align:centure;">
            <button class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left">Click
                Me</button>
        </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove `jqm-demos.css`. Load css/js in `head` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple typo. The first `<ul>` in your header's navbar is not closed.
Somehow jquery-mobile dont like this and stops rendering with a error. You should see this error in your browsers dev tools.

If your references to jquery and jquery-mobile are correct. it should work if you close the `<li>` tag

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery Mobile Demos</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<!-- jQuery Mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="_assets/js/index.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Mobile -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">

  <div data-role="header">
    <div class="ui-btn-active" data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Find Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Call Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-content" data-role="main">
    <ul data-filter="true" data-insert="true" data-role="listview">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Brussels</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Dublin</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Cape Town</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" style="text-align:center;">
    <button class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left">
      Click Me
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Beside that, you have others error in your code.

1. You should insert your personal javascript code `<script src="_assets/js/index.js"></script>` after jquery and jquery-mobile. If you do so, you're always sure, that all libraries are loaded before you use them in your "personal" javascript file.
2. There is no need to include the same CSS Files twice. like you did with 
   `css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css` and `_assets/css/jqm-demos.css`
   In Jquery-mobile, there is the possibility to include CSS and/or Javascript file inside of the data-role="page" container. But in this case it makes absolut no sense.
3. The class `ui-btn-active` is unnecessary inside of the navbar `<div>`. If you want to set a button of your navbar active, you have to include this class inside of the `<li>` tag
4. And you have a typo inside of your footer. `centure`

Comment: Geez, I can't thank you enough. It worked exactly how I wanted it to!  I'm actually going to copy and save your answers and keep practicing and reading through your code. I am still learning, but typo errors and not closing tags is something I must work on and work through and be precise.

Comment: Also, Thank you for explaining my other errors and where and where not to put certain codes. I was wondering if I had gotten those wrong by chance, but didn't know where else I would put them. Again, thank you very much. I appreciate the help a lot!